# How to add the message <Major upgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of product name is already installed"/> in bootstrapper project

Tags: wix

How to add the message  in bootstrapper project.

If I execute the bootstrapper package exe file Second time means it is showing the uninstall option not "A newer version of product name is already installed". Pls help

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- AllowSameVersionUpgrades -> Always upgrade, never allow two versions to be installed next to each other -->
    <!-- AllowSameVersionUpgrades causes ICE61 which must be ignored -->
    <MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed. Setup will now exit." AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes"/>
```

Comment: Thanks milanb. But we cannot add majorupgrade schedule in bundle project. Only in product.wxs we can add that comment